# Could we increase contrast for links on meta?

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, design, meta

Some recent style updates changed the link color on meta:

[image: example]

Did you spot both visited links there?  I had trouble doing so.  Even the two unvisited ones are a little hard for me to see.  (I grant that my vision isn't as good as yours.)  I have even more trouble when there's a link in a comment, where the fonts are smaller.

Could we adjust the link colors to provide a little more contrast?

(I don't have a pre-change screen shot, sorry.)

Comment: [meta-tag:feature-request]?

Comment: @msh210 I dithered over that and wasn't sure which way to go.  I'll go ahead and add it -- why choose? :-)  (When we figure out which it should be we can fix it, but this way it shows up in filters.)

Comment: I've heard of this tripping up enough other people that I think it's fair to label this [meta-tag:bug] instead of [meta-tag:support].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm adding underline on links to make them pop out more (only on meta). It will be live after our next production build.

Comment: It's live. Thanks!