# On Meta Mi Yodeya, every link has a dotted underline. Is this ideal?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, meta

## Background

It's true that modern web browsers always provide a solid underline to all links by default, and that web designers like to override this behavior. On quora.com, Edo Amin [explains](https://www.quora.com/When-should-a-dotted-underline-be-used-in-an-interface) why: if there are too many underlines on one page, the page can appear far too busy.

## The current situation

Due to the aforementioned reason, most or all Stack Exchange sites seem to override the default behavior of adding a solid underline to every link.

- On Mi Yodeya, links are colored at all; they have no underlines. This is fine.
- On Meta Stack Exchange, links are colored; they have no underlines at all. This is also fine.

## My question

- On Meta Mi Yodeya, all links are colored and have dotted underlines. Is this ideal?

## What to do

Please see the answer(s) below. Each answer describes a proposed solution. Upvote whichever proposed solution you like. If you don't like any of the proposed solutions, please post your own.

Comment: Once our discussion has reached a consensus, we should edit my question to have a "feature-request" tag. I don't know for sure, but my hunch is that Stack Exchange staff monitor Meta Mi Yodeya and watch for questions with this tag.

Answer (score 2):

It's nonstandard to make all links have dotted underlines, and it's not the best idea. Nowadays, on the Web, a dotted underline is usually used to indicate an abbreviation; when you hover your mouse over the abbreviation, you'll see an infotip (tooltip) with its expansion. Click [this link](http://www.quackit.com/html_5/tags/html_abbr_tag.cfm) to see a page with a demo.

Therefore, to avoid confusion: Dotted underlines may be used to signify abbreviations, but should preferably not be used to signify ordinary links.

I propose that links on Meta Mi Yodeya should be changed so that they have either:

- a solid underline, or
- no underline at all, plus colors with better contrast. The new colors will ensure that visited links remain [nice and visible](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3993/could-we-increase-contrast-for-links-on-meta).